# How to select columns only containing the certain string in SAS

Tags: sas

Is it possible to keep only columns that contain a certain character in SAS?

For example, i have a data set that look like this:

```
data3_Median_Max, data2_Median_Min, data43_Median_Max, age_Sum, data2_Sum
```

I want to create a new data set that only consists of columns that a word 'Median' in their name. I managed to extract the columns thats starts from 'data'.
My code:

```
    data test;
        set work.test2;
        keep data:;
    run;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me if those are variable names, data set names or values in a single variable. Can you please clarify your data structure? Showing an example of what you have, what you want as output based on the input and what you've tried is the recipe to get you an answer as quickly as possible.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697314/sas-keeping-only-columns-that-contain-a-certain-character?rq=1

Comment: @Tom Just a reminder you can hit "close" and close as a duplicate.